# ajax in mvc with default settings

Tags: ajax, default

We have a lot of ajax calls in our application.

Can we set basic parameters such as headers, async, datatype in layout file and use  / override only the parameters that change when making the call.

eg. In layout file

```
  $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        headers: { "Accept-Encoding": "compress, gzip" }
  });
```

eg: in calling file

```
$.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("GetState", "Country")",
        async: true,
        data: { search: search, StateId: state },
        success: function (data) {   
        }
  });
```

Comment: For this you can create a common.js file, in which you can define the basic parameters for ajax

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` itself already has [`ajaxSetup()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) method to setup default settings which will enabled for future AJAX callbacks. Here is an example to use default setup for all view pages with same layout page:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    headers: { "Accept-Encoding": "compress, gzip" }
});
```

Then you can add other settings in view page as well:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("GetState", "Country")",
    data: { search: search, StateId: state },
    success: function (data) { 
        // do something  
    }
});
```

If you want to override default settings, you can define AJAX options and pass it through `$.ajax()`:

```
var config = {
    type: 'POST',
    url: "@Url.Action("GetState", "Country")",
    data: { search: search, StateId: state },
    async: true,
    dataType: "text"
};

$.ajax(config);
```

However, the usage of `ajaxSetup()` is not recommended because of this reason:

> The settings specified here will *affect all calls* to `$.ajax` or
>   Ajax-based derivatives such as `$.get()`. This can cause **undesirable
>   behavior** since other callers (for example, plugins) may be expecting
>   the normal default settings. For that reason *we strongly recommend
>   against using this API*. Instead, *set the options explicitly in the
>   call* or define a simple plugin to do so.

Hence, it is better to create default settings in a single variable or function and extend it whenever necessary, since basically AJAX settings contains key-value pair (KVP) objects. Use [`jQuery.extend()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) function for merging default settings into other one, then pass it as AJAX callback parameter:

```
// Layout page
var defaultSettings = {
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    headers: { "Accept-Encoding": "compress, gzip" }
};

// View page
var viewSettings = {
    url: "@Url.Action("GetState", "Country")",
    data: { search: search, StateId: state },
    success: function (data) { 
        // do something  
    }
};

var settings = $.extend({}, defaultSettings, viewSettings);
$.ajax(settings);
```

Additionally [`jQuery.isPlainObject()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isPlainObject/) may be used before sending AJAX request to make sure that all parameters are valid KVPs (it should return `true` for `PlainObject` type).